# Any problem with creating provisioning profile with old Iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have quite an old IPhone available (first edition SE) that I want to use to make a provisioning profile together with a Mac computer.

Will there be an issue using such an old IPhone for this purpose?  Will the apps that I build with this profile only target an IPhone SE?